# NativeScript Storybook or alternative

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Since a year, we are using [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) to develop our angular web applications, as well as our ionic cordova apps.

Now we want to evaluate if NativeScript might be a better solution for our needs. We are currently wondering if it is possible to make storybook work with NativeScript as it has proven to be quite useful for UI development.

I know that NativeScript is officially not supported by storybook - but React Native is so in theory it should be possible, though I couldn't find any information on this.

My question now is: Has anyone been able to make storybook work with NativeScript? Or does an alternative exist that I'm just unable to find? Or are there at least some concepts/tools to develop components in isolation?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: @miladfm unfortunately not. There has been a prototype around that integrates appetize (which basically allows you to run native apps in a browser) with storybook. But there seems to be no progress for over a year now. The issue is/was tracked here https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7708 but has been closed due to staleness. I think the demand is not big enough compared to the amount of work that would need to done...

Comment: A pity :(
Thank you

Comment: @miladfm I'm not sure when this was added, but I just stumbled upon this: https://github.com/storybookjs/native 
Since we dropped NativeScript in favor of PWAs, I did not test this out yet, but this looks like it is exactly what I wanted back when I created this issue. Maybe it helps you! :)

Comment: I will test it. Thank you @pascalpuetz